# dp:// search root for windows search indexer

Tags: windows-search, search-indexing

The search indexer on my computer has recently been acting up. Looking into it, it seems there is a strange search root `DP://` that contains several 100k items:

[image]

It seems to contain a copy of my file system (this is the CSV exported by the Indexer Diagonstics app via Index Item Stats > Export Details to file):

[image]

**What is that search root? What is it supposed to do? I can of course just disable it, but maybe it is trying to do something useful?**

The computer is question is running Windows 11 Pro, 22H2

Comment: Do you have FIle History turned on or have done recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DP://` index location is created when the `File History` feature is enabled. It lets Windows Search index your file history and allows you to search through it.

If you no longer use File History then you can remove the location but removing it while the feature is still enabled could cause problems.

You can find the protocol information in the registry at

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\Gather\Windows\SystemIndex\Protocols\DP\0
```

That shows that the protocol is linked to the ProgID `FhSearchPHLibrary.FhSearchProtocol`. If we check that in HKCR, we can find the CLSID here:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FhSearchPHLibrary.FhSearchProtocol\CLSID
```

And then we can check what DLL it's coming from here:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{B5A123C0-3893-4F1C-8599-00F4B82F2C99}\ProgID
```

Which reveals that it's linked to the following DLL `fhsrchph.dll`. If you decompile it with something like JEB you can see references to the `DP://` protocol but that's beyond my understanding at this point.